# Create multiple parent pages in comfortable mexican sofa cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, comfortable-mexican-sofa

Sincerely saying I am new to ruby on rails. Since I want to use content management system in my existing ruby 2.0.0 rails 4.1.1 application .
I am using comfortable_mexican_sofa 1.12.1

I choose to use comfortable Mexican sofa cms it was just awesome and easy to implement and use in application but when I tried to create second parent it was taking as child of first parent only.

Throughout I was not able to create second new parent is this cms functionality is like this only or I am doing any wrong. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one root page. This is by design. Imagine you have `/about` and `/help` pages. You may think that they don't have a parent page, but they do. It's a `/`. That one, obviously, can't have a parent page.

If you have your own controller serving `/` (usually a `root_path`) then you'll just have a blank page in CMS.